# Cordova window.localStorage.key getting Error

Tags: cordova, cordova-3

I have a simple cordova localstorage code

```
window.localStorage.setItem("key", "value");
var keyCount = window.localStorage.length;
alert("lenght " + keyCount);
var keyname = window.localStorage.key(0);
var value = window.localStorage.getItem("key");
window.localStorage.setItem("key2", "value2");
keyCount = window.localStorage.length;
alert("lenght2 " + keyCount);
```

Once i add in `window.localStorage.key(0)` , the code will stop there and won't run the second alert, if i remove `window.localStorage.key(0)` it will display the second alert. I reference the code from cordova documentaion http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#localStorage

May i  know what is the problem ?

Comment: What platform are you using cordova on? and what version of Cordova?

Comment: i am using cordova 3.1.0 and Android platform~

Comment: @benka i am using cordova 3.1.0 and Android platform~

Comment: thx, i was trying to run that code but it was running fine. Tried it on Chrome and Android 4.3 too. Didn't have any issues with `window.localStorage.key(0)`. Only thing I could think about, are you sure the first setItem works? can you read it back before running the .key(0)?

Comment: if you put another alert right after .key(0); like `alert("key [0]:"+window.localStorage.key(0));` does it work?

Comment: @benka As long as i include this code 'window.localStorage.key(0)' it will stop. i also have no idea . May i have a look at your sample ?

Comment: I used the code from your question.

Comment: @benka may I know how you debug in it chrome ? as my chrome always get hang during the load of cordova

Comment: right click on the page > inspect element > select the "console" tab in the new window

Comment: @benka have you try to run it in Android 4.2 AP17 ?

Comment: no, only on 4.3. I'll try it tomorrow on 4.2